# “Couldn’t create temporary file” error when erasing free space on startup disk

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, disk-utility

When I tried to erase space on Disk Utility, it couldn't create a second temporary file for my startup disk.

[image: Secure Erase Free Space failed with the error: Couldn't create temporary file.]

Comment: permissions or format error - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/172274/85275

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue while erasing free space on El Capitan. I was doing it from the terminal, and this was likely the error you ran in to:

```
Error: -69847: Couldn't create temporary file
Underlying error: 1: POSIX reports: Operation not permitted
```

As @Tetsujin mentioned, there is a solution in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172271/couldn-t-create-temporary-file-error-when-erasing-free-space-on-external-disk/172274#172274) — though, in this case, I think the easiest solution is to run the operation via the command line, with `sudo`. From a terminal window, you should be able to do:

```
sudo diskutil secureErase freespace 0 "/Volumes/[Disk Name]"
```

This isn't the accepted answer in the linked issue, but it's one of the answers...and way easier than all the other solutions.

The `0` in the command specifies that you want to overwrite the free space with zeros...there are other "more secure" options, although there are arguments that [erasing free space may not be necessary](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/securely-erase-mac-ssd/) at all, when you have a solid state hard drive.